# C#: annoying mistake during making back up of sql database

Tags: c#, database, backup

I am trying to make my application which have aim to make backup of database on disk and also send it through ftp or mail.
So I made a research and finally I wrote project of Windows service and another project in console which is making a backup of database. Both are working well and both are written in the same Visual Studio but when I am trying to put code of making backups in Windows service it doesn't work. I can't understand why. I tried put code instead of example (which is creating a file and writing one line there and this part is working well) and I even tried to make another method to do it and then call this method.

Windows service is completely the same as **[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3938/Creating-a-C-Service-Step-by-Step-Lesson-I)** and in the SpadesAdminService class instead of

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("SpadesAdminSvc", 
                                      ServiceName + "::Execute()");
```

I made this code (is working well - making an empty file on my disk every 5 seconds, should be written "text to file" but files are appearing !):

```
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite("C:\\place\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss") + ".txt"))
        {
            Byte[] napis = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("text to files"));
            fs.Write(napis, 0, napis.Length);
        }
```

My class of making back up (alone is also working well):

```
namespace makeBackUpConsole
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string dbname = "exampleToniDatabase";
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sqlcon.ConnectionString = @"Server=GRAFIKA-2\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;" + "Database=exampleToniDatabase";
        string destdir = "C:\\place\\";
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(destdir))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\place\\");
        }
        try
        {
            sqlcon.Open();
            sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("backup database  " + dbname + " to disk='" + destdir + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss") + ".Bak'", sqlcon);
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlcon.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Backup database successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error During backup database!");
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am copying this class instead of my code to making txt files and Windows Service is not working. Here is a code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace toni.exampleService.Services
{
public class exampleAdminService : exampleServiceBase
{
    public exampleAdminService()
    {
        this.ServiceName = "exampleAdminSvc";
    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();
    }
    protected override int Execute()
    {
        //using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite("C:\\development\\toni\\dd\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss") + ".txt"))
        //{
        //    Byte[] napis = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("Dzień i godzina: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss"));
        //    fs.Write(napis, 0, napis.Length);
        //}

        string dbname = "exampleToniDatabase";
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        sqlcon.ConnectionString = @"Server=GRAFIKA-2\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;" + "Database=exampleToniDatabase";

        string destdir = "C:\\place\\";

        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(destdir))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\place\\");
        }
        try
        {
            sqlcon.Open();
            sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("backup database  " + dbname + " to disk='" + destdir + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss") + ".Bak'", sqlcon);
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlcon.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Backup database successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error During backup database!");
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

}

Of course all libraries as well linked.

Looking for any advice, please help me.

Thank you in advance and have a nice day.

edit:
Hey, problem solved.
I created a database account (not Windows account) in sql management studio and I putted this account User Id and Password directly into my code in C# in Windows Service.
Anyway maybe somebody will use my code :)
Thanks for reply.

Comment: "doesn't work" - how exactly does it not work? Compiler error? Exception thrown? Computer melting?

Comment: which user is running the windows service? Seems like being a rights management problem...

Comment: @Corak
sorry for haven't described this, "doesn't work" mean that is compiling, then I am installing service and when I am turning on this service is working a while (~5 sec) and stopping always, file is not appearing. No exceptions. Just service is turning off by herself after few seconds forgetting gimme my file.

Comment: @chris6523 
Thank you so much about issue with right, maybe problem is about that, but I tried to put currently user, admin, everything, I tried with NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService, NT AUTHORITY\LocalService and few others.

Comment: You shouldn't use MessageBox.Show in a service.

Comment: @sgmoore - exactly. System log or some other kind of logging should be used. Looks like an exception is thrown and caught (maybe even by working successful), then it's attempted to show a MessageBox, which throws the next exception which causes the service to shut down.

Comment: @up and 2up
yes you are right also, I delated this too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked that a Windows Service has permissions to write a file in the location you are specifying. Services don't necessarily run as a user, so don't assume that where you can write a file your service can too.

Have you tried writing to a folder underneath c:\ProgramData?

If you don't know precisely what the problem is then you need to find out. Try adding `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();` at service startup and then track the changes inside the debugger.

Comment: the same Windows Service can make in the same location file .txt but have problem to put .bak there.. so I dont think so that is about permission.
I tried C:\ProgramData also there is not appearing my file :(
I will read more about System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
THANKS !

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Service you have programmed is using "Integrated Security" for your SQL Server.

If you don't want to enter login credentials in your code, you should either set the executing user to your local account or grant the required user (e.g. LocalSystem) access to your database in your SQL Management Studio.

Usually a Windows Service is running as LocalSystem, LocalService or NetworkService. Just change the setting for your Windows Service in services.msc

Comment: thanks, I should have "Intergrated Security" set up for 'true' or 'sspi', I tried also put User Id and password in code but it didn't helped still
this setups about account in code should be ok, because in the version in console everything is going ok with that data
in service.msc I tried a lot with LocalSystem, LocalService and is for sure not NetworkService, anyway I tried too